# TYPO3 - Best way to create 100000 pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

What's the best way and what are the min requirements to create 100000 pages? Columns, ... . I want to profile 100000 records under rootline pid70:

```
-Cars[70]
--UniqueRecordIDX
--......
```

... so that they are accessible via root path (with realurl) like

```
/cars/
/cars/uniquerecordid/
...
```

I create a partial which gets loaded if the page is under rootline 70. I've created a couple of pages (default, en & de) in the BE and for them it's already working. But what about the rest?

I thought about a php script to create new records (if uniquerecordid doesn't exist yet) in table pages. I don't need any page settings except for that it must exist, accessible via nice looking path (realurl) and with language switch. Starting with two options default, de and en.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to use pages including all their settings and options? 
Maybe you can create an extension for your purpose and create records then you only need 1 "page" record for use as "detailpage" which content is dynamically changing by the requested record of your extension.

Comment: Well, I thought about the option to be able to add/load more functionalities (extensions) to each record/profile when requested. Is this also possible within an extension and the list/detail structure? I actually do have the later already in place. Thanks

Comment: Each record of an extension can be extended by options as much as you want. Depending on the options you can of course change the view of list and detail pages. The only big benefit of pages is the possibility of arranging content elements like in a WYSIWYG editor.